# What is this sed command doing?

Tags: sed

I am looking for non printable characters into a file, and I found this [web page](https://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/linux-unix/display-nonprintable-characters-in-text-file/).

It shows the following command:

```
sed "l" file
```

If I am not mistaken, according to [man](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed), this option is:

> List out the current line in a ''visually unambiguous'' form.

Moreover, when I run this command on a fake file with one line, the output is as follow:

- The line is displayed twice, but each displayed line (in the output) contains at most 69 bytes of the input line. The rest of the line is displayed at the next line.
- The second time the line is displayed, it is in its full length.

**fake file**

```
toto, titi, tatafdsfdsfdgfgfdsgrgdfgzfdgzgffgerssssssssssssssssssssssssss
```

**Command**

```
sed "l" fake_file
```

**output**

```
$ sed "l" fake_file 
toto, titi, tatafdsfdsfdgfgfdsgrgdfgzfdgzgffgerssssssssssssssssssssss\
ssss$
toto, titi, tatafdsfdsfdgfgfdsgrgdfgzfdgzgffgerssssssssssssssssssssssssss
```

## Questions

- What does ''visually unambiguous'' exactly mean ?
- Why is the output like this ? I was expecting only one line with the `$` sign at the end. I was also not expecting output to be displayed on 69 bytes max.

## Environment

Tested with same output on:

- sed (GNU sed) 4.7
- sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2

Answer (score 0):

By default, `sed` outputs the result after processing a line. If you handle the output yourself, tell `sed` not to output the line by the `-n` switch.